# How to pass console input to another function in console application

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, .net-6.0

I have attached menu in console application. User can select a currency at runtime to see the product prices. I am stuck on point, how to save user selected currency type and then use it to display product details.
User journey I am thinking is
User will see the available options to select. If user selects other than 4,  then default price details will appear in USD. If user selects option 4, then user can choose the currency type and again main menu options will be displayed as shown in image. Then user will see the product details in selected currency.

[image]

My sample code is like below.

```
  public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            var shouldRun = true;
            DisplayOptions();
            
            dynamic selectedCurrency ;

            while (shouldRun )
            {
                Console.Write("Enter an option: ");
                var input = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine("\n");

                switch (input.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad1:
                    case ConsoleKey.D1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Printing all products");
                        _productListVisualizer.OutputAllProduct();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad2:
                    case ConsoleKey.D2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Printing paginated products");
                        _productListVisualizer.OutputPaginatedProducts();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad3:
                    case ConsoleKey.D3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Printing products grouped by price");
                        _productListVisualizer.OutputProductGroupedByPriceSegment();
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad4:
                    case ConsoleKey.D4:
                        Console.WriteLine("Printing available currencies.");
                        _productListVisualizer.GetListofCurrencies();
                       //here I am reading the currency choice. How will I pass it to other function like OutputAllProduct and rest 2.
                        Console.Write("Select Currency. Default is USD. : ");
                        selectedCurrency = Console.ReadKey();
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.Q:
                        shouldRun = false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid option!");
                        break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                DisplayOptions();
            }

            Console.Write("\n\rPress any key to exit!");
            Console.ReadKey();

           await _host.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
        }

        private static void DisplayOptions()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Choose an option:");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Print all products");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - Print paginated products");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Print products grouped by price");
            Console.WriteLine("4 - Change Currency.");
            Console.WriteLine("q - Quit");
        }
    }
```

Comment: where in your code are you running into an issue?  what are you expecting to happen vs what is actually happening?

Comment: @frankM_DN I am not getting how can I pass the selected currency input to other functions.

Comment: Why are you asking input in a BackgroundService? A worker (of service) is supposed to run without any UI

Answer (score 0):

Your functions need to accept a parameter for the selected currency or if the functions live in your Worker class you could use a global variable.

Function accepting parameter:

```
...
string selectedCurrency = "3"; // default value of USD input key
...
switch (input.Key)
{
   ...
   case ConsoleKey.NumPad1:
   case ConsoleKey.D1:
      Console.WriteLine("Printing all products");
      _productListVisualizer.OutputAllProduct(selectedCurrency);
      break;
   ...
}
...

  
public static void OutputAllProduct(string selectedCurrency);
```

Global variable:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
   private string SelectedCurrency;
   protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
   {
      ...
      // assign new value to selected currency (case ConsoleKey.NumPad4: or case ConsoleKey.D4:)
      SelectedCurrecy = Console.ReadKey();
      ...
   }

   ...

   private static void OutputAllProduct()
   {
      // access to global variable SelectedCurrency here
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach and not getting selected value and always being passed as USD.

Comment: What do those functions look like?